# unexpected sync.Pool allocation

Tags: go, benchmarking

all, been learning Golang for a month now and came across this problem . Basically I'm trying to reuse a []byte from sync.Pool to do some hashing.

I've added a minimum viable sample for reproducing it below:

```
type mWriter struct {
    pool *sync.Pool
}

func (m *mWriter) writeSpan(span interface{}) {
    haha := m.pool.Get().([]byte)
    // in real code some actions here instead of simply setting haha[0] = 1
    haha[0] = 1
    m.pool.Put(haha)
}

func NewWriter() *mWriter {
    bytepool := &sync.Pool{
        New: func() interface{} {
            return make([]byte, 16)
        },
    }
    return &mWriter{
        pool: bytepool,
    }
}

func Benchmark_WriteSpan(b *testing.B) {
    c := NewWriter()

    b.ResetTimer()
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for it := 0; it < b.N; it++ {
        c.writeSpan(nil)
    }
}
```

Under my impression sync.Pool doesn't allocate new memory for []byte, but I'm seeing extra allocation with the `m.pool.get()` here.

> Benchmark_WriteSpan-12        30000000            47.6 ns/op        32 B/op          1 allocs/op
>   PASS

What are the explanations behind this? I also tried some more simple benchmark here:

```
func Benchmark_2(b *testing.B) {
    // Initializing pool
    pool := &sync.Pool{
        New: func() interface{} {
            return make([]byte, 4)
        },
    }
    b.ResetTimer()
    b.ReportAllocs()
    // Get hold of instance one
    one := pool.Get().([]byte)
    one[1] = 1
    one[2] = 2
    // Submit back the instance after using
    pool.Put(one)
}
```

But this shows no allocation:

> Benchmark_2-12                2000000000           0.00 ns/op        0 B/op          0 allocs/op

Appreciate any help here! (If this is not how sync.Pool is used, any suggestions?)

**Edited:**

OK, I added a simple loop inside the benchmark to writeSpan and now it gives following benchmark:

```
func Benchmark_WriteSpan(b *testing.B) {
    c := NewWriter()

    b.ResetTimer()
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for it := 0; it < b.N; it++ {
        for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
            c.writeSpan(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

> Benchmark_WriteSpan-12         5000000           226 ns/op         160 B/op          5 allocs/op

Looks like the pool allocates 32B in every write, shouldn't it be reusing the same byte[] after first get?

**Update**
@JimB I do have some logic in real code which does updating the byte slice and hash on it. like the following:

```
    byteSlice := ds.poolInstance.bytepool.Get().([]byte)
    copy(byteSlice[:len(ds.hashSalt)], ds.hashSalt)
    span.TraceID.MarshalTo(byteSlice[len(ds.hashSalt):])
    hashVal := ds.hashBytes(byteSlice) 
    ds.poolInstance.bytepool.Put(byteSlice)
```

I'm not sure if this counts as free list maintained as part of a short-lived object, could you be more specific on this?

Comment: You have no loop for your benchmark in the second example. 0.00 ns/op is faster then light ;-)

Comment: The pool starts empty. When you `Get` from the pool and there's nothing in the pool to return, it calls `New`. Your `New` has an allocation (as it must). Your second benchmark effectively doesn't run because it has no loop on `b.N` (hence the reported zero execution time and zero memory usage).

Comment: `Under my impression sync.Pool doesn't allocate new memory for []byte`; your impression is incorrect. `sync.Pool` can help reuse memory, but it can't magically create it from nothing.

Comment: @Jude, after the update, I think what you're seeing is the overhead of the `sync.Pool`. If you allocate a much larger slice in the `New` function, I think you'll see roughly the same thing. Also, because no work is being done here, the items are being returned to the pool faster than they can be recycled, so there is going to be more allocations than there would be in a real use case.

Comment: From the `sync.Pool` docs: `a free list maintained as part of a short-lived object is not a suitable use for a Pool, since the overhead does not amortize well in that scenario`, which is exactly what you're doing here.

Comment: @Jude: that depends on the lifetime of the `mWriter`. if you're wondering whether `sync.Pool` will help you here, benchmark it under realistic scenarios. If it measures out as being faster or more efficient, then use it. The main point is that it's not free.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for the comment. I've found out the reason behind it. Not related to sync.Pool though:)

Answer (score 3):

I think I found out the reason behind it. In my real code, I used to have:

```
bytepool: &sync.Pool{
    New: func() interface{} {
        return make([]byte, length)
    },
},
...
...
bytepool.Get().([]byte)
```

somehow when I changed it to

```
bytepool: &sync.Pool{
    New: func() interface{} {
        byteP := make([]byte, length)
        return &byteP
    },
},
...
...
bytepool.Get().(*[]byte)
```

the allocation drops to 0. So sorry folks looks like not an issue with sync.Pool but the underlying data structure. Thanks for your comments though!